# Regex to match word surrounded by non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to match and find index of word either surrounded by space or special characters. For example:

```
To find: test
this is input test : True
this is#input_ : True
this isinput : False
thisisinputtest: False
this @test is right: True.
```

How do I match this and find index. My current regex fails: `(?i)[^a-zA-Z0-9]test[^a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: This is a different case because in my case, #test_ should return index of test not #test.

Comment: `_` is a word, not a special character. Besides, `this is#input_` cannot be `True`, where is the word `test` there? The `#test_ ` is missing in your test cases.

Comment: *Non alphanumeric. Besides, on a match I want index of "test". All other examples gives a full match!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wait, '_' is not a character?

Comment: To get the index, just access `matcher.start()`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I understand that, but the answer in the linked question will match #test and give start index of `#` not test. Which is what I want.

Comment: Then what is your code? Please share. Still, please check the `this is#input_ : True`  test case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127981/discussion-between-maxsteel-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Besides, since you need the index of the search word, it is easier to use lookarounds - `String pat = "(?<!\\p{Alnum})test(?!\\p{Alnum})";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you need to use lookarounds in your case:

```
(?<!\p{Alnum})test(?!\p{Alnum})
```

The negative lookbehind `(?<!\p{Alnum})`  will fail the match if there is an alphanumeric char present to the left of the `test`, and the negative lookahead `(?!\p{Alnum})` will fail the match if there is an alphanumeric char right after `test`.

See the testing screenshot:

[image]

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/MAXJg8):

```
String str = "this is#test_ :";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\p{Alnum})test(?!\\p{Alnum})");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.start());
}
```

Alternative way: match and capture the search word, and print the start position of the 1st capturing group:

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\\P{Alnum}(test)\\P{Alnum}");
...
System.out.println(matcher.start(1));
```

See this [Java demo](http://ideone.com/Vl6O1M)

**NOTE** that in this scenario, the `\P{Alnum}` is a *consuming* pattern, and in some edge cases, `test` might not get matched.

Comment: Although I wasn't clear in the question (sorry about that!), this is exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot!

Comment: For those who only need alphabetic characters and not alphanumeric, you can use `"(?<!\\p{Alpha})test(?!\\p{Alpha})"`

Comment: @DatNguyen: Note that `\p{Alpha}` works with ASCII only letters by default (if you do not specify the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag). To match any Unicode letters without depending on flags, use `"(?<!\\p{L})test(?!\\p{L})"`.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew!

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying to understand your question. You are looking for `test` that is surrounded by a special character (_ included) or a space?
But yet you say `this is#input_ : True`. I am not sure if I am picking this up wrong but how is that true in that case?

Anyway I have got the regex `[\W\s_](input|test)[\W\s_]` that matches all your cases defined as true.

- \W matches any non words
- \s matches any whitespace
- _ matches any underscore - Has to be defined on its own as this is a word
- From my confusion of the test mentioned I have the regex search for both input and test

Also I user [this](http://regexr.com/) site anytime I work with Regex as I find it so useful.

Not sure if this is the answer your looking for but let me know if I am wrong and I will try again